# Can't create an Executable from Python Script using Pyinstaller on macOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

1. I Installed `pyinstaller`: `pip install pyinstaller`
2. Open terminal and typed : `cd /Users/cn/PycharmProjects/Final_5/venv`
3. `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`
4. then i moved the `main.exe` in the folder where all my dependencies are

Error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/main.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qtmodern'
[19444] Failed to execute script main
```

But everything is Installed, every module is installed. Why is it giving me this?